# (Пример из Unity3d) Проблема с понимаем типов в C#, как оно работает?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять несколько строчек кода, вот на пример:

`public GameObject moveObject;` – Как я понимаю, тут мы объявили переменную `moveObject` ссылочного типа (потому что `GameObject` – это класс), но как она должна работать? Ведь это же не `Int` или `String`, а оператор `new` мы не использовали, чтобы выделить память и получить объект.

```
public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour{

    public GameObject moveObject;
    public Transform targetPosition;
    public float speed;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        moveObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(moveObject.transform.position, targetPosition.position, Time.deltaTime*speed);
        moveObject.transform.LookAt(targetPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Объект в переменную помещается в другом месте.

Comment: собственно, если смотреть со стороны C# данный код и не должен работать. Вариантов может быть несколько: нужно самому написать инициализацию в Start, либо данные публичные поля инициализируются в другом месте

Comment: Либо у вас не весь код класса, либо внешние силы инициализируют эти публичные поля (почему не свойства?)

Comment: @Андрей, причина может крыться в Unity

Comment: @Grundy, никогда не работал в Unity, но это всё ради производительности?

Comment: @ Alex Krass - ТОЧНО ! Спасибо друг, да действительно обьект помещается самой средой Unity в эту переменную, я как-то это пропустил !

Comment: @Андрей, Не могу сказать, может быть просто отпечатком давно минувших дней

Comment: @Artem, если разобрался, то можешь либо написать развернутый ответ, либо удалить вопрос

Comment: @Андрей вроде не только, там они еще связанны с редактором, если правильно помню. Но что точно, там некоторая куча объектов создается на этапе инициализации самого главного класса и потом они путешествуют по всему проекту подобным образом.

Comment: Это способ явного связывания объектов на сцене с кодом. Например: создали на сцене какой-то объект (какой - неважно, будь то меш или просто спрайт). Повесили на ваш объект скрипт, в котором указали public GameObject moveObject;. После чего в редакторе, в инспекторе этого объекта появится поле типа GameObject, в которое прямо в редакторе можно поместить какой-то объект, например дочерний или его же самого.

Comment: Сначала ознакомтесь с классическим C# или прочитайте стотью про модификаторы доступа (static, private, public) https://goo.gl/oKuNUW

Answer (score 1):

Большинство объектов и полей в Unity которые вы используете внутри компонентов сериализуются средствами ядра. Когда вы добавляете поля в коде, как только переходите в редактор он обновляет отображение компоненты и для скрипта запускает сериализацию. Соответственно новые созданные поля должны быть заполнены значениями по умолчанию. Боюсь что все немножко сложнее на деле (в новых скриптах можно назначить значение по умолчанию в редакторе щелкнув на сам скрипт), но в целом выглядит как то так.

Answer (score 0):

И так для будущих коллег, которые возможно столкнутся с таким же вопросом и непониманием почему оно работает ! Всё оказалось очень просто, в скрипте к Unity вы описываете ссылки для будущих обьектов и логику их работы, а сами обьекты вы уже прикрепите из самой Unity к этому скрипту, а Unity сама неявно выделит память под него. То есть в моем случае *moveObject* это ссылка на обьект персонажа (префаб) например машина, вот у нас есть этот скрипт, добавляем его в Unity где редактор укажет что к *moveObject* нужно прикрепить обьект, а остальное Unity берёт на себя ...

Comment: Учите Unity по учебнику, и таких вопросов не будет возникать.